# Pandas dataframe intersection with varying groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a large pandas dataframe with varying rows and columns but looks more or less like:

```
time   id    angle  ...
0.0    a1    33.67  ...
0.0    b2    35.90  ...
0.0    c3    42.01  ...
0.0    d4    45.00  ...
0.1    a1    12.15  ...
0.1    b2    15.35  ...
0.1    c3    33.12  ...
0.2    a1    65.28  ...
0.2    c3    87.43  ...
0.3    a1    98.85  ...
0.3    c3    100.12 ...
0.4    a1    11.11  ...
0.4    c3    83.22  ...
...
```

I am trying to aggregate the `id's` together and then find `id's` that have in common time-intervals. I have tried using pandas groupby and can easily group them by `id` and get their respective groups with information. How can I then take it a step further to find `id's` that also have the *same* time stamps?

Ideally I'd like to return intersection of certain **fixed time intervals** (2-3 seconds) for similar id's with the **fixed time interval** overlap:

```
time  id  angle  ...
0.0   a1  33.67  ...
0.1   a1  12.15  ...
0.2   a1  65.28  ...
0.3   a1  98.85  ...

0.0   c3  42.01  ...
0.1   c3  33.12  ...
0.2   c3  87.43  ...
0.3   c3  100.12 ...
```

Code tried so far:

```
#create pandas grouped by id
df1 = df.groupby(['id'], as_index=False)
```

Which outputs:

```
time  id  angle ...
(0.0   a1  33.67
...
0.4   a1  11.11)

(0.0  b2  35.90
0.1   b2  15.35)

(0.0  c3  42.01
...
0.4   c3  83.22)

(0.0  d4  45.00)
```

But I'd like to return only a dataframe where `id` and `time` are the same for a fixed interval, in the above example .4 seconds.

Any ideas on a fairly simple way to achieve this with pandas dataframes?

Comment: Can you add exected output? Because I think sorting is not what need `df = df.sort_values(['id','time'])`

Comment: You can `groupby` more than one column eg `df.groupby(['id', 'time'])`

Comment: I am not sure that helps achieve my end purpose of finding time intersections for fixed intervals of time  @BeRT2me

Comment: @anothercoderbro You're right, but to be fair your question was worded a little poorly. I'd addressed various ways to `filter` your `groupby` in my answer.

Comment: @anothercoderbro - What means fixed interval? It means need values between `0` and `0.4` if overlap for each `id` ? Or something else? Maybe sample data should be changed if need something else.

Comment: It means the ideal setup would be I could search the dataframe to find 3-second intervals that are present for multiple ids. Eg: From time 2.1 to 5.1 there were 5 ids that all had recorded angles and it returns them as well as others that satisfy the consecutive angle measures for 3-second intervals. @jezrael

Comment: It would be great to have a function that just returns all 3-second intervals where their exist consecutive time-data for each id @jezrael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need filter rows by some intervals - e.g. here between `0` and `0.4` and get all `id` which overlap use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) first, then [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1 = df[df['time'].between(0, 0.4)].pivot('time','id','angle')
print (df1)
id       a1     b2      c3    d4
time                            
0.0   33.67  35.90   42.01  45.0
0.1   12.15  15.35   33.12   NaN
0.2   65.28    NaN   87.43   NaN
0.3   98.85    NaN  100.12   NaN
0.4   11.11    NaN   83.22   NaN
```

There are missing values for non overlap `id`, so remove columns with any `NaN`s by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and reshape to 3 columns by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
print (df1.dropna(axis=1))
id       a1      c3
time               
0.0   33.67   42.01
0.1   12.15   33.12
0.2   65.28   87.43
0.3   98.85  100.12
0.4   11.11   83.22

df2 = df1.dropna(axis=1).unstack().reset_index(name='angle')
print (df2)
   id  time   angle
0  a1   0.0   33.67
1  a1   0.1   12.15
2  a1   0.2   65.28
3  a1   0.3   98.85
4  a1   0.4   11.11
5  c3   0.0   42.01
6  c3   0.1   33.12
7  c3   0.2   87.43
8  c3   0.3  100.12
9  c3   0.4   83.22
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to define the filter you're asking for:

```
df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 4)
    # OR
df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: x['time'].eq(0.4).any())
    # OR
df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: x['time'].max() == 0.4)
```

Output:

```
    time  id   angle
0    0.0  a1   33.67
2    0.0  c3   42.01
4    0.1  a1   12.15
6    0.1  c3   33.12
7    0.2  a1   65.28
8    0.2  c3   87.43
9    0.3  a1   98.85
10   0.3  c3  100.12
11   0.4  a1   11.11
12   0.4  c3   83.22
```

Comment: `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` if you want the index to go to `0 - 9`